# get path to app_Data folder from a class in Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to find a way to access files in App_Data from classes in Model. I know we can use HttpContext.Server.MapPath in controller but I cannot use it in Model classes to use xml files stored there

Comment: Map it in the controller and then pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: I have a hundred paths to make...

Comment: Just pass in the App_Data base path string once and then concat each of those in the model.

Comment: lol, didn't thought this!!

Comment: But how am I going to call a controller method from a Model class?